# How send invitation to Facebook Friends from iOS application

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone suggest me how can I generate or create App Link URL for sending invites facebook friends ? I checked Facebook SDK Documentation but cannot found any useful answer about App Link URL.

Thanks.